# the usage of "site"

Tags: word-usage

[A post on Apple Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Park) says

> Its scale and circular design, by Norman Foster, have earned the structure a media nickname “the spaceship". Located on a suburban **site** totaling 175 acres (71 hectares), it houses more than 12,000 employees ...

where the word "site" is used. As per Cambridge Dictionary , I understand [what "site" means](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/site) there:

> a place where something is, was, or will be built

Cambridge Dictionary also gives these examples

> a building site
>
> The company hasn't yet chosen the site for the new hospital.

I guess I understand the meaning of the sentence

> Apple Park is set in 175 acres of land.

The question is about the usage of the word "site", does the following sentence sound natural?

> Apple Park is set in 175 acres of **site**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apple Park is set in 175 acres of site.

No, this does not sound natural, and is grammatically incorrect. We use the word **of** to indicate the quantity of **uncountable** nouns:

> A kilo **of** sugar
>   100 hectares **of** land

**site** is **countable**: a site is the place where something is, or will be- a pin in a map, that doesn't give any indication how big the site is. With countable nouns, you just use a number:

> 10 apples
>   100 sites.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. The previous one, "Apple Park is set in 175 acres of land", is grammatically incorrect and sounds natural, right?

Comment: "Set in" doesn't sound right to me here. It sounds more natural to say, "Apple Park is located on 175 acres of land" or (as in the original sentence) "Apple Park is located on a 175-acre site."

Comment: @WXJ96163 what do you think is grammatically incorrect about "Apple Park is set in 175 acres of land"? It seems fine to me.

Comment: @SarahT, note that, as far as I can tell, Apple Park is a store where you can buy Apple products. It doesn't occupy all of the 165 acres: it is **set in** (located within the boundaries of) 165 acres of land.

Comment: @JavaLatte According to Wikipedia, Apple Park is the name of the corporate campus that includes the giant "spaceship" building as well as several other buildings?

Comment: The wiki article is confusing: in places it uses the term Apple Park to descibe the building, and at other times suggests that it is the whole site. "Its [Apple Park's] scale and circular design, by Norman Foster,[8] have earned the structure a media nickname “the spaceship".[9][10][11]", also look at the scale diagram on the right, half way down the document: the circular building is labelled Apple Park.